# OneLogin Provisioning using SCIM

Tags: provisioning, onelogin, scim

I am creating a SCIM complient APP for OneLogin. I have implemented SCIM API. It works fine for /Users Request.

But I am not getting what will be the format for /Groups Request and when it will be sent. In which format they are sent and How to assign groups to people. And how to apply mapping for it..I Have read this article( https://developers.onelogin.com/scim/implement-scim-api ) on provisioning for this but it doesn't give me clear insights. 
Also, Can one user be in multiple groups?

Comment: Hey akash, I am also working on OneLogin Provisioning using SCIM, and need your help, can you help me how did you make it working for /Users?

Comment: Yeah Sure, you can ask question and send me link or contact me on my email akash.modi@lyearn.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to configure your application to first enable provisioning for the Groups attibute in your SCIM connector (this tells OneLogin that your application supports Groups)

Once that's done, you should 'Refresh Entitlements' and OneLogin will call the app's groups endpoint to retrieve what groups are available to assign users to.

From there you can add Rules to the application in OneLogin that assign users to groups and users can be assigned to as many groups as you want.

Details can be found here: https://developers.onelogin.com/scim/create-app

Comment: I have asked one login support and they told me that there is nothing like this group in which user can be in multiple groups..

Comment: This can be used only for defining roles and sign on privilages.

OneLogin Support : " In OneLogin, a user can only have 1 group, but can have multiple roles.  AD group membership and OneLogin Roles can usually be pushed to a SCIM enabled application."